# Unexpected Output trying to filter a list in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

Let there be a list of words, and I want to remove all the words containing a particular letter.

This is what I tried

```
Wordlist = ["abcd","cdef","efgh","ghij","ijkl","klmn","nope","wow"]
BadLetters = "d"


for word in Wordlist:
    for BadLetter in BadLetters:
        if (word.count(BadLetter) > 0):
            Wordlist.remove(word)

print(Wordlist)
```

Expected Output: 'abcd' and 'cdef' removed
`['efgh', 'ghij', 'ijkl', 'klmn', 'nope', 'wow']`

Actual Output: only 'abcd' removed
`['cdef', 'efgh', 'ghij', 'ijkl', 'klmn', 'nope', 'wow']`

What might be causing the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: may not be a good idea to modify the list while iterating over it

Comment: Create a new list instead: `wl = [w for w in Wordlist if not any(l in w for l in BadLetters)]`

Comment: Because you are making change in the same list which you are iterating, it will always skip the position  which is removed.

e.g the if statement would become true for the first item of the list. Now in the next iteration, it will access the second item. But since the list is now changes, the first item points to "cdef" which would be skipped.

Comment: try this :     `Wordlist = [w for w in Wordlist if not any(BadLetter in w for BadLetter in BadLetters)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to delete elements from a list while iterating it.

Try this:

```
Wordlist = ["abcd","cdef","efgh","ghij","ijkl","klmn","nope","wow"]
BadLetters = "d"

Wordlist_new = []
for word in Wordlist:
    for BadLetter in BadLetters:
        if (word.count(BadLetter) > 0):
            pass # Wordlist.remove(word)
        else:
            Wordlist_new.append(word)

print(Wordlist)
print(Wordlist_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove the words that have "d" inside:

1. loop through every word
2. check the existence of the BadLetters inside `if BadLetters in word:`
3. remove the word that has the bad letter

You can explain more what you want code to solve.

Comment: point `2` is wrong: you test if the string `BadLetters` is found exact in the string `word`, the OP want if any character of `BadLetters` is in `word`: delete the `word`